# QComboBox as function input argument in QT

Tags: c++, qt, function, arguments, qcombobox

I was playing with QT and I found a small issue. (I am really new in Qt).
After search about that, I did not find anything.
The problem is:
In header file:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
    namespace Ui {
class jAudio;
}

class jAudio : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit jAudio(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~jAudio();

private:
    Ui::jAudio *ui;

private slots:
    void jSetup (void);
    void jInfo (QString);
    void jFillComboBox(QComboBox, QStringList);
    void on_bRecord_clicked();
};
```

And I declare the method in .cpp file like:

```
#include "jaudio.h" 
#include "ui_jaudio.h"
void jAudio::jFillComboBox(QComboBox comboBox, QStringList data){
    for (int i = 0;  i< options.count(); i++){
        comboBox->addItem(data[i],i);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code then the error appear:

```
..../jAudio/jaudio.h:25: error: 
‘QComboBox’ has not been declared
 void jFillComboBox(QComboBox, QStringList);
```

Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Thnak you very much!!

Comment: I don't see any includes in your header nor source file

Comment: And you maybe as new in C++ as in Qt. Not only no includes, you are not supposed to pass any arbitrary object by value without knowing that that would work. `QComboBox` should be passed as a pointer or `QComboBox*`.

Comment: Hi. I just notice I did not copy that includes in the question. In the header file, there is only one include: "#include <QMainWindow>" and in .cpp file are two: #include "jaudio.h"
#include "ui_jaudio.h"

Comment: @JavierGonzalezMoncayo Change `void jFillComboBox(QComboBox, QStringList);` to `void jFillComboBox(QComboBox *, QStringList);` and `void jAudio::jFillComboBox(QComboBox* comboBox, QStringList data)`.

Comment: @eyllanesc, I tried your solution but still happening the same error..... Do you have any idea about what is happening?

Comment: Share your code through github or gist and I will help you solve it.

Comment: Here we go: https://github.com/JavierMoncayo/jAudio . The file involve are: "jaudio.h" and "jaudio.cpp". Thank you very much. You are the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jAudio.h: add `#include <QComboBox>` and `#include <QStringList>`. And change `jFillComboBox` to `jFillComboBox(QComboBox*, QStringList)`, as previously mentioned in comments. The reasoning for the second part is that `QComboBox` is derived from `QWidget`, and `QWidget` objects cannot be copied. If you've come from other, higher-level languages, the concept of non-copyable objects and passing-by-pointer (or reference) may be foreign to you. If that's the case, consider looking through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) and the links there.